# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone-views

My view child didn't appear, I have 3 views : the first one calls the view 2,
the view 2 appends a list of skills in its view in this way

```
initialize: function(option) {
      Backbone.Validation.bind(this);
      console.log(this.collection);
      this.collection.fetch({ data: { page: 'no'} });
      this.collection.on('add', this.add, this);
    },

 render: function (){
      SkillView.__super__.render.apply(this);
      this.collection.forEach(this.add, this);
    return false;
 },
```

I have a error in `SkillView.__super__.render.apply(this);`, can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: SkillView was not intialize => 'view/Skill-view'